# Rename android application signing key file

Tags: android, keystore

i want to rename application signing key.but i have doubt that whether will cause any effect on key file signature.In my case application is already uploaded on play store.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which part do you wanna rename? You can rename name.keystore part without any issues.

Comment: i want to rename key file name.e.g if my singing key file name is "Test" then i want to rename "Test" to "Sample Application"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can simply rename the file name. There will be no problem with that. I have done this before.

Comment: we can rename our key file.I test it with sample application.First i upload sample application on play store then rename that key file and upload new apk to play store.Play store accept apk without any error.